# Angular2 URL fragment ignored in Firefox

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a home page that consists of several different sections:

- Introduction
- Services
- Projects

All of the content exists on the same page.  My navigation structure uses Angular2 fragments to scroll to the specific section based on user selecting Introduction, Services, or Projects.  The HTML for navigation looks like this:

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 130vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu-bar primary large-condense large-align-center medium-expand large-text-center">
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/home" href="#homePageTop">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/home" fragment="services" href="#serviceContainer">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/home" fragment="projects" href="#projectContainer">Projects</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<section id="homePageTop" class="home-desktop-container container">
  INTRODUCTION HERE...
</section>


<section id="serviceContainer" class="serviceContainer container">
  SERVICES HERE...
</section>


<section id="projectContainer" class="projectContainer container">
  PROJECTS HERE...
</section>
```

This code works as expected in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge in that I can click on services and projects links and am scrolled to the correct section of the home page.  However, in Firefox, I am not scrolled to the correct section.  In Firefox, the URL in the browser changes to reflect the fragment (http://localhost:4200/home#projects), but I am never taken to the targeted section.  The home page simply reloads and I'm at the top of the page.

Any ideas on why this works in Chrome and Edge but not Firefox?  No errors are emitted to the console either.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can check this answer https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595#issuecomment-244232725

Comment: What's the firefox version?

Comment: Firefox version 49.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Using Firefox 49.0.1 with the "Run code snippet" link; the Home, Services, and Project links seemed to work the same as with Chrome for me.

Could your Firefox browser have old files cached?

What happens after pressing F5 in your Firefox browser to refresh the cached files?